# How to remove filter components row from an extendedDataTable in richfaces

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, richfaces, filtering, richdatatable

I have an **extendedDataTable** with a column like this

```
<rich:column id="exampleId"
             filter="#{exampleFilterBean.exampleFilterMethod}"
             filterValue="#{exampleFilterBean.exampleFilterValue">
             <f:facet name="header" >
                  <h:outputText value="Header" />
             </f:facet>
             <h:outputText value="#{exampleFilterBean.example.exampleAttribute}" />
```

I don't want to display the control bar with the filter box because I'm using external filters and JavaScript API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily hide them by adding a css-command:

```
.rf-edt-flt-c { display:none; }
```

Also the input boxes will be removed when you remove the `filter`/`filterattribute` - attributes

A third way is to remove them via javascript using extended data tables `onready`-attribute

```
onready="$('.rf-edt-flt-c', this).each(
                function(n){ 
                    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
                 });"
```

Hope it helps...